# FreeRDP resize grab area is one pixel

Tags: gnome, rdp

I'm on Ubuntu 23.04, Gnome 44.3, X11. This has annoyed me for some time though and I think it's been the case since at least 22.04.

For most applications, the "resize grab area" seems to be about five pixels, give or take. However, for FreeRDP it seems to be one pixel, which only can be seen/used when moving the mouse toward the frame from outside its window. This makes it quite a fairly painstaking process to resize FreeRDP windows. I'm guessing this is the case because those five-ish pixels of grab area is usually inside the window frame, and FreeRDP starts passing mouse control over to its client once the mouse is inside its window.

Is there a way to extend the grab area a few pixels outside the window frame? Or other workaround to easily resize FreeRDP windows?

Comment: I had this annoying behaviour in _all_ windows when still using xfce and Gnome. My workaround was to bind a key combination (RCtrl+RShift for example) to the "Resize Window" action. Otherwise I'm not aware of a way to change that. But you can get used to that workaround pretty easily.